# Vectorize Matlab sum

Tags: beginner, matlab, vectorization

I have the following Matlab function:

```
function [res] = a3_funct(x)
    res = 0;
    for i = 1:size(x,1)
        res = res + abs(x(i))^(i+1);
    end
end
```

It's emulating this equation:

\$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^{i+1}\$

Here is an example use:

```
>> a3_funct([1,2,3]')

ans =

    90
```

I know I should be able to use the `sum()` function to make this faster, but how do I get the exponents in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vectorized approach:

```
res = sum(abs(x(:).'.^(2:numel(x)+1)))
```

Read more about vectorization techniques [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).

Thus, your function would look like this:

```
function res = a3_funct(x)
    res = sum(abs(x(:).'.^(2:numel(x)+1)));
return
```